# Choosing a random string from a dictionary / array to display in a UILabel when a button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've been playing around with an app that will display a random joke when a button is pressed.

I have declared two outlets (one for the button and one for the label which will display the joke). I have successfully got the code to display a line of text when the "jokeButton" is pressed. Although, how can I type in a large bank of jokes then display a random one when the joke button is pressed.

I have tried messing around with an NSArray and NSDictionary and did some googling but with no success.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self->jokeLabel.text = (@"Welcome to The Joke Panel!");
}

- (IBAction)jokeWasPressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Joke Button Was Pressed");
self->jokeLabel.text = (@"Why did the chicken cross the road? -- To get to the other side!");
}
```

Thank you so much for any help!
PS Sorry I've just started learning!

Comment: If you are going to have a large joke base, you might want to consider using core data. Even if your not, it might be worth looking into it as it is a very useful part of iOS worth learning. However for less than ~500 entries arrays are good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with creating an array of strings. The next step would be to generate a random number and use that as the index value to get the string from the array.

Look up `arc4random` for information on creating a random number.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare "NSMutableArray *arrJokes;" globally

//Initialize array to hold strings which will essentially be the Jokes
arrJokes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Add jokes
[arrJokes addObject:@"Joke 1"];
[arrJokes addObject:@"Joke 2"];
[arrJokes addObject:@"Joke ..."];
[arrJokes addObject:@"Joke N"];

//generate a random index between 0 and arrJokes.count
int randomIndex = arc4random()%arrJokes.count;

//pick the string that is at this randomIndex in arrJokes and set it on the label
[jokeLabel setText:arrJokes[randomIndex]];
```

Comment: `arrJokes` is not mutable as written.

Comment: @rmaddy : oops, yeah. \*sigh\*